How to generate a random number based on clock and recent blockhash?
i want to generate a random number in native rust on solana by using clock and recent blockhash.
Right now I'm simply generating it by
let clock = Clock::get()?;
let random_number = (clock.slot % 100) as usize;
msg!("random: {:?}", random_number);

I know the RecentBlockhashes is deprecated, but i don't know the substitute.
I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance !

Unless this is for a hobby project, do not generate randomness like this. It's insecure, as the clock time and slot number is predictable. Recent blockhashes won't help you either as they're visible to everyone. You cannot generate a secure random number on chain without any external oracle. Fortunately service providers for this exist, such as Switchboard.
